# Customization of hint in EditText

Tags: android

I have included EditText in my UI. I want to give my users more specific information about what to enter in EditText due to which my hint is large enough to be appeared completely in the view. Is there any way by which I can make my hint fully visible and make it appear more appealing.Or is there any other way to give complete info to users rather than giving whole info in Hint.

[image]

Comment: Try with putting \n in string
<string name="hint">Experienc (Can include no. of years \n previous Word \n....your complete string.</string>

Answer (score 0):

You can make the font size of the hint smaller so that more of the hint could be visible. I am not sure if this is what your looking for but you can do this by adding this to your Edit Text:

```
android:textSize="(size)sp"
```